# Cordova / PhoneGap TDD: How to use Jasmine and Karma to test mobile app?

Tags: cordova, tdd, jasmine, cordova-3, karma-runner

```
To be able to develop in TDD
As a PhoneGap developer using Jasmine and Karma
I want to be able to run Jasmine spec files inside a PhoneGap application
So I can verify my Cordova specific code in my unit tests
```

Based on [karma #472](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/issues/472), it doesn't work for some/most people, but some claim it can be done.

What I'm trying to achieve is to have access to the Cordova environment (eg. FileSystem API, battery events, etc.) in my spec files/tests. (I do mock a lot of services by the way, but I'd like to access the real API)

I have tried to redirect the Cordova app to Karma runner page with `window.location = 'http://karma:8080'`, and while I can load the base `cordova.js` file inside the tests, `deviceready` never fires (see ticket), plus I'm unable to grab the JS code that are required to have plugin functionality (ie. code depending on plugins can't be tested).

I've tried to create an `<iframe>` pointing to Karma inside the Cordova app, but that also couldn't access `cordova`.

I have found [others are injecting cordova](https://github.com/AppGyver/steroids-runtime-tests/blob/9db1f8502993ef95448b5e87ead881fda07b61d2/test/cordovainjector.js) to `window.parent`, but I don't really see how that could work (I can't access `window.parent` from my `<iframe>`).

I have tried to do these in [ripple-emulator](https://www.npmjs.org/package/ripple-emulator) and in Android AVDs, with the same lack of success.

Any pointers are really appreciated. I'm using Cordova 3.4.1 on Android (not targeting iOS), and latest Karma & Jasmine, plus AngularJS 1.3.

Comment: Did anything happen here for you?

Comment: No, I never got any further.

Comment: I haven't done any Cordova stuff lately, so nope.

Answer (score 0):

You could create two separate files `index_real.html` and `index_test.html` in your `www` folder.
`index_real.html` is the `index.html` which you have currently. `index_test.html` would be instrumented with Jasmine version of `index_real.html`.

Create `real.sh`:

`cp index_real.html index.html
cordova run`

and `test.sh`:

`cp index_test.html index.html
cordova run`

Running `real.sh` will run your not instrumented version of application, and `test.sh` will run your test suite. If you setup `index_test.html` close to your `index_real.html` your will have UI automation tests, or if you will put standard Jasmine test runner you will have unit testing suite.